# Mat-dialog: keep it open when routing to another component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a button in a component comp1 that opens a dialog,
then in this dialog a button that redirects to another component comp2 (with routerlink)
What I need is, once I am done with comp2 and I click save, I want to be back to comp1 with the dialog opened.
What is a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario, whenever you come back to `component 1` from `component 2`, Pass one query params to detect that you are coming from component 2.

And on the basis of that query params you can programatically open a dialog whenever needed.